# Additional Android APIs not shown in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I installed **Android SDK Manager** two months back. I got the **Android 2.3.3 SDK** installed, but I do not quite remember the steps I followed, because I am new to Android development. Now, when I open Android SDK manager, I see only the "**SDK Platform Android 2.3.3**". I cannot see any other API versions which I am interested in (eg. higer versions). However, I do not see any options for selecting any other API versions.  I have already tried the following:

1) Tried to locate "**Available Packages**" option, but I cannot locate this option in Android SDK Manager.

2) Tried **Tools -> Options -> "force https://...sources"**. After doing this, it connected to this URL but the View remains the same,i.e I cannot see a list of available packages that I can install. I have not given any proxy address in the boxes.

3) I have run the Android SDK manager with administrator privilege.

4) I am not running Android SDK manager from eclipse, i.e. I am running it directly. (at the time of writing I am downloading eclipse again because I had uninstalled it. So, I haven't tried opening Android SDK manager from eclipse).

I am attaching the screen shot of the Android SDK manager. (with the version number of SDK manager in the About dialog box)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Help -> Install new software`

Click on `Add` button

Add the link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Expand `Developer tools`. Inside that select `Android DDMS` and `Android Developer Tools`

Uncheck `Show only latest versions`

Click `finish`...

Restart eclipse .

Go to `Help -> Check for updates`. Complete all the updates

Then go to `Window -> Android SDK Manager`

You'll find all available versions..

Comment: Deepzz: You have confused me. As I mentioned, I do not have eclipsed installed yet. Do you mean to say that I can't get the list of new SDKs without eclipse?

Comment: @pradeeptp sorry i thought u've already installed eclipse :P Download eclipse and check this..

Comment: @pradeeptp : actually i dont knw about that.. Hope u have solved that problem now..

Comment: Worked for me, but its pretty awful that the packages aren't there without having to jump through hoops with Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If some API levels are not listed in Android SDK Manager (API 14 for example) try to check Obsolete check box on the bottom of the Android SDK manager window.