# Cannot see SDK Platform entry in Android SDK Manager for API > 18

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

What I can see:

[image]

What I have tried:

1. [Android SDK Manager doesn't load the latest Android SDK Platform (API 17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956688/android-sdk-manager-doesnt-load-the-latest-android-sdk-platform-api-17)
2. [Missing SDK platform Android, API 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916966/missing-sdk-platform-android-api-18)
3. [I cannot download android SDK platform in sdk manager anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437432/i-cannot-download-android-sdk-platform-in-sdk-manager-anymore)
4. [Cannot see SDK Manager menu option in Android Studio settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772785/cannot-see-sdk-manager-menu-option-in-android-studio-settings)
5. [Additional Android APIs not shown in Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169027/additional-android-apis-not-shown-in-android-sdk-manager)

LOG:
[image]

Although, when I browse the failed links in my brwser I can see the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late answer. Well, it's seem your connection was not able to transfer packages throw HTTPS protocol. You should to try turn on option to connect throw simple HTTP (Tools/Options/Others/Force ... using http...). Then restart SDK Manager.

[image]